# This has a ScrollToAsync parameter which you can set to "true" or "false"

Tags: forms, xamarin, scrollview

The Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView class has a method ScrollToASync method which takes a parameter for animation, which can be set to be "true" or "false".  When its set to true, the scrolled output is smoooooth, but does anyone have an idea of the performance implications?  Supposing I was to output 1000+ lines smooooothly, would my app incur less overhead if I didn't use animation by setting this parameter to "false" ?

Comment: I think that depending on your requirement. If you want the smooth effect, you can set the parameter to "true". If you want you app incur less overhead and save time, you can set the  parameter to "false". You can also write your own ScrollView and customize the animation to meet your requirement.

Comment: Yes thanks ... but I already knew that.  I was more interested in finding out the performance impact of the smooth option